# How to add spell checking to multiple languages on PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, ide, spell-checking

I have strings on my code that are in French and Spanish and PyCharm keeps notifying me about typo issues with those strings.

How can I make PyCharm to spellcheck these words without notifying me about these `typos`? Should I add a plugin or something for these languages?

I searched for plugins and some appeared but the file wasn't recognized by the plugin manager.

Answer (score 1):

No need to install plugins (as I initially thought so).

Accessing the menu `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Natural Languages`, you can click on the `+` button, and a list of available languages will be displayed to you, where you can select them and the spelling files will be download and the spelling for the selected languages will be activated on the editor.

[image]

---

#### Example

Here I'm looking for spelling on Russian and a list of available languages to download is displayed:

[image]

I selected Russian and the download box is displayed:

[image]

And the spell checker of Russian is now available along with other languages:

[image]